# Association Bonus

Tags: support, reputation

When I connected my Stack account to the Magento Beta, I did receive the 100 points for an association bonus.

I wondered if anyone could explain why that happened? Two of my colleagues received the bonus.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have generic question, do not forget to [check the faq](http://magento.stackexchange.com/faq) first and then, search [the *global* meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the [StackExchange FAQ](https://magento.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

Comment: Cheers, makes sense!